# Same badness cause different space in the same sentence in TeX?

Tags: tex-core, badness

On page 29 of **The TeXbook**, Mr. Knuth show the same sentence with the same badness, but those have different space between their word. What is the reason and how to understand the badness here?

[image]

Comment: as it shows on the right, one is squeezed, one is stretched badness is always positive and shows how far white space is from its natural size

Comment: Does badness have direction? But why does the same sentences have different directions?

Comment: badness 0 means white space is its natural size, if the space stretches or shrinks then badness will be larger than 0, the exact formula is in the book

Comment: This is just a case? As in reality, the same sentenced shouldn't have different directions?

Comment: In reality TeX does not typeset sentences or single lines but always paragraphs. It uses several passes for one paragraph, but not always all, but stops if a pass was successful (fits the selected parameters). So, yes, the same sentence can be typeset different in different paragraphs. And even the same paragraph can be typeset different, depending on the active parameters like `\tolerace`, `\emergencystretch`, `\hyphenpenalty` … But with the same parameters the same paragraph will not typeset different.

Comment: Look at the source code for that, the sentence is _forced_ to spread to different lengths to generate different badness values. The two with badness 12 are `\hbox spread-.333333em{The badness of this line is 12.}`  and `\hbox spread.5em{The badness of this line is 12.}` so one squeezes and one streched both by values the author must have calculated to generate badness of 12 in this case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Now, I don't know what is the `spread` here, so I didn't look at the source code.

Comment: in latex that would be `\makebox[some small length]{a sentence of text}` and `\makebox[some large length]{a sentence of text}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But, it seems that `spread` would adjust the space between words not the entire sentence.

Comment: spread specifies the width of teh sentence box, text then adjusts the space between words to achieve that size. that is exactly what badness measures. How much the space between words has changed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `spread-.333333em` only has -0.333333em, but the sentence is obviously wider than this. How to understand the `-0.333333em`? I guess it may be the space between words?

Comment: Why guess? You have the texbook open. It means to make the sentence box -.33em shorter than it would be naturally, and the other one makes it .5em wider

Comment: @DavidCarlisle God. That’s what it means! But when I don’t understand, I first guess and then try to verify.

Comment: "Same badness cause different space in the same sentence in TeX?" "Badness" does not _cause_ spacing. It is the other way around: Not "badness" affects spacing but spacing affects "badness"."Badness" is the "dimension" for measuring how much the spacing done by TeX deviates from optimal spacing. The quality of spacing can decrease and thus the "badness" can increase **both** in case spacing leads to words being closer to each other than in case of optimal spacing **and** in case spacing leads to words being farther apart from each other than in case of optimal spacing.

Comment: "But why does the same sentences have different directions?" What does "direction" mean in this context? Typesetting is done from left to right. Spaces between words are horizontal glue and thus can be smaller than or equal to or larger than spaces between words in case circumstances allow TeX to do optimal spacing between words. In any case spaces between words lead to words being separated from each other. They (should) never lead to the last characters of a word overlapping with the first characters of another word.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Directions mean stretched or shrinked.

Answer (score 6):

It helps looking at the source code

```
\begindisplay \hbadness10000
\hbox spread-.666667em{The badness of this line is 100.}&
  \quad(very tight)\cr
\hbox spread-.333333em{The badness of this line is 12.}&
  \quad(somewhat tight)\cr
\hbox{The badness of this line is 0.}&
  \quad(perfect)\cr
\hbox spread.5em{The badness of this line is 12.}&
  \quad(somewhat loose)\cr
%\hbox spread 1em{The badness of this line is 100.}&
% \quad(loose)\cr % then "looser"
\hbox spread 1.259921em{The badness of this line is 200.}&
  \quad(loose)\cr
%\hbox spread 1.713em{The badness of this line is 500.}&
% \quad(bad)\cr % then "worse"
\hbox spread 2.155em{The badness of this line is 1000.}&
  \quad(bad)\cr
\hbox spread 3.684em{The badness of this line is 5000.}& % actually 4995!
  \quad(awful)\cr
\enddisplay
```

Knuth did the calculations separately looking at the formula and computing the badness by hand. One can use `\badness`, that always keeps the badness of the last built box.

```
\hbadness10000

\leavevmode\hbox spread-.666667em{The badness of this line is 100.}\quad\the\badness

\leavevmode\hbox spread-.333333em{The badness of this line is 12.}\quad\the\badness

\leavevmode\hbox{The badness of this line is 0.}\quad\the\badness

\leavevmode\hbox spread.5em{The badness of this line is 12.}\quad\the\badness

\leavevmode\hbox spread 1.259921em{The badness of this line is 200.}\quad\the\badness

\leavevmode\hbox spread 2.155em{The badness of this line is 1000.}\quad\the\badness

\leavevmode\hbox spread 3.684em{The badness of this line is 5000.}\quad\the\badness % actually 4995!

\bye
```

Actually the first line prints 1000000 instead of the predicted value 100, but for different reasons: 100000 is a special value that cannot be achieved from the formula and is used to denote an overfull box (you can read about it at the very end of chapter 12).

[image]

The badness is a measure of how much the interword spaces need to be stretched or shrinked. It is always nonnegative.

Note how stretching or shrinking is achieved by the `spread` instruction.